# Lost windows 8 data recovery

Tags: dual-boot

I used an installation CD drive to run Ubuntu.

When I booted with installation CD on restart, it gave me an option to either "try" or "install" Ubuntu. I chose install.

During the course of installation, I did not know how to partition and all, so chose Logical Volume Management, and finished the installation successfully.

I removed the CD and restarted. I assumed now the laptop will ask for my preference of Operating Systems - Ubuntu or Windows 8- but it does not! It always starts Ubuntu! Also, the boot buttons (F1,F2,etc.) don’t work while restarting the laptop

I think I have lost Windows :(

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Check whether the partitions are still there: `sudo parted -l`. If they are, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.